# When does a weapon inflict damage?

Tags: hearthstone

If a minion is redirected by a misdirection on its owner who has a weapon equipped, will it take damage from the weapon? Will the weapon lose a durability counter (I'm not sure how are these called in english, the number of times you can use a weapon)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if a minion attacks a hero with the weapon exposed, they will take the damage from the weapon, but the weapon will not lose any uses.

Comment: What causes a weapon to be exposed? Are they only exposed on a player's turn?

Comment: @ahsteele yes weapons are only exposed on the players turn.  Otherwise they would be much too powerful.

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to add the clarification for those that may not have understood. Probably should have just stated it rather than asking questions. ;-)